# bootstrap 20 grid, 3 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have a question on how I can do this.

bootstrap 20 grid, 3 columns

Is it possible? Or should use 24 grid?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-15">
        <div class="row">HERE I NEED equal 3 columns :)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either, If it was me I would use 3 columns as 5 with 2 as spacers.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-15"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"><!--Spacer--></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"><!--Spacer--></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very simple and very usefull :) Thanks